# Extract specific file from complex war archive structure

Tags: zip

I'm new in Unix, am trying to extract specific file(by using one command) form this kind of folder structure:
`.../file1.ear/file2.war/folder1/folder2/fileToExtract.txt`

What I do now is extract the first ear file to a folder (unzip), then extract the second war file to a folder and only then I am able to open the txt file in Unix.

Answer (score 3):

By combining `unzip` and `jar`, you can extract the various components using pipes:

```
unzip -p file1.ear file2.war | jar x folder1/folder2/fileToExtract.txt
```

The `-p` option to `unzip` instructs it to extract `file2.war` to its standard output, without anything else; then `jar x` reads `file2.war` from its standard input and extracts `folder1/folder2/fileToExtract.txt`.

Both tools in isolation aren't sufficient as far as I can determine: `unzip` can't read archives from its standard input, and `jar` can't extract to its standard output...

Answer (score 0):

You cold use mc ([midnight commander](https://www.midnight-commander.org/)). You can even edit the files without unpacking.